# Zip lists in jq's objects construction by {} instead of multiplying them like default

Tags: json, jq, transpose

A JSON object like this:

```
{"user":"stedolan","titles":["JQ Primer", "More JQ"],"years":[2013, 2016]}
```

And, I want to convert it with lists(assume all lists have equal length `N`) zipped and output like this:

```
{"user":"stedolan","title":"JQ Primer","year":2013}
{"user":"stedolan","title":"More JQ","year":2016}
```

I followed `Object - {}` example and tried:

```sh
tmp='{"user":"stedolan","titles":["JQ Primer", "More JQ"],"years":[2013, 2016]}'
echo $tmp | jq '{user, title: .titles[], year: .years[]}'
```

then it output:

```
{"user":"stedolan","title":"JQ Primer","year":2013}
{"user":"stedolan","title":"JQ Primer","year":2016}
{"user":"stedolan","title":"More JQ","year":2013}
{"user":"stedolan","title":"More JQ","year":2016}
```

It produces `N*N ...` lines result, instead of `N` lines result.

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`transpose/0` can be used to effectively zip the values together. And the nice thing about the way assignments work is that it can be assigned simultaneously over multiple variables.

```
([.titles,.years]|transpose[]) as [$title,$year] | {user,$title,$year}
```

If you want the results in an array rather than a stream, just wrap it all in `[]`.

https://jqplay.org/s/ZIFU5gBnZ7

---

For a jq 1.4 compatible version, you'll have to rewrite it to not use destructuring but you could use the same `transpose/0` implementation from the builtins.

[`transpose/0`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/jq-1.6/src/builtin.jq#L193):

```
def transpose:
  if . == [] then []
  else . as $in
  | (map(length) | max) as $max
  | length as $length
  | reduce range(0; $max) as $j
      ([]; . + [reduce range(0;$length) as $i ([]; . + [ $in[$i][$j] ] )] )
            end;
```

Here's an alternative implementation that I cooked up that should also be compatible. :)

```
def transpose2:
    length as $cols
      | (map(length) | max) as $rows
      | [range(0;$rows) as $r | [.[range(0;$cols)][$r]]];
```

```
([.titles,.years]|transpose[]) as $p | {user,title:$p[0],year:$p[1]}
```

Comment: Thx! It's really a ingenious and elegant solution! By the way, it works with `jq1.6` and reports error "syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting '$'" with `jq1.4`.

Comment: Unfortunately 1.4 doesn't support destructuring or transpose. Fortunately the destructuring just makes it nicer to look at and can be worked around. Transpose could probably be pulled out and used from the builtins. (https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/jq-1.6/src/builtin.jq#L193)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output to have the keys in the order indicated in the Q, then the solution is a bit trickier than would otherwise be the case.

Here's one way to retain the order:

```
with_entries( .key |= (if . == "titles" then "title" elif . == "years" then "year" else . end) )
| range(0; .title|length) as $i
| .title |= .[$i]
| .year |= .[$i]
```

The (potential) advantage of this approach is that one does not have to mention any of the other keys.