# How to create array of json objects using jq and set to var in bash

Tags: arrays, json, bash, shell, jq

I have like this variables in my bash script:

```
server1_name = 'server-1'
server1_url = 'http://server-1.net'

server2_name = 'server-2'
server2_url = 'http://server-2.net'
```

How I can create like this json using my variables and set to new var:

```
[
  {
    "name": "server-1",
    "url": "http://server-1.net"
  },
  {
    "name": "server-2",
    "url": "http://server-2.net"
  }
]
```

What I tried:

```
export jsonArray = $("[{\"name\":"$server1_name",\"url\":\"$server1_url\"},{\"name\":"$server2_name",\"url\":\"$server2_url\"}]" | jq -rec .)
```

Comment: Do you want a dynamic solution, or are those examples the real values?

Comment: Those examples the real values @0stone0

Comment: You can show both options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass your strings using `--arg`, then you can create the JSON as expected:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

server1_name='server-1'
server1_url='http://server-1.net'

server2_name='server-2'
server2_url='http://server-2.net'

result=$(jq -n \
    --arg name1 "$server1_name" \
    --arg url1 "$server1_url" \
    --arg name2 "$server2_name" \
    --arg url2 "$server2_url" \
    '[ { "name": $name1, "url": $url1 }, { "name": $name2, "url": $url2 } ]')

echo "$result"
```

Will produce:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "server-1",
    "url": "http://server-1.net"
  },
  {
    "name": "server-2",
    "url": "http://server-2.net"
  }
]
```

Comment: How I can set result to new var to export it?

Comment: Please see my edit, forgot you want it in a other variable!

Answer (score 1):

You can construct two arrays of names and urls, then adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57283652/1126841) to "zip" the two arrays together into the desired array of objects.

```
jq -n \
    --arg name1 "$server1_name" \
    --arg url1 "$server1_url" \
    --arg name2 "$server2_name" \
    --arg url2 "$server2_url" \
'[$name1, $name2] as $names |
 [$url1, $url2] as $urls |
  [([$names, $urls] | transpose[]) as [$name, $url] |{$name, $url}]'
```

The benefit is that as the number of name/url pairs grows, you only need to modify the first two filters that define `$names` and `$urls`; the rest of the filter stays the same. You could even separate this into separate uses of `jq`, to facilitate the definition of a large list of servers.

```
names=$(jq -n --arg v1 "$server1_name" --arg v2 "$server2_name" '[$v1, $v2]')

urls=$(jq -n --arg v1 "$server1_url" --arg v2 "$server2_url" '[$v1, $v2]')

jq -n \
   --argjson names "$names" \
   --argjson urls "$urls" \
   '[([$names, $urls] | transpose[]) as [$name, $url] | {$name, $url}]'
```